# rEFInd didn't detect the proper Linux distro and therefore doesn't show the right icon, how do I change that?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac, refit

I'm currently triple-booting Mac Windows and Ubuntu on my computer, and according to the rEFInd website, the software should be able to automatically detect Linux distros and show the correct icon... Mine doesn't.

Rather than showing an Ubuntu logo, it's simply just showing Tux, which is fine for identifying the correct OS, but it's not exactly displaying what system I'm using on that spot.

I admit this is a very minor issue, but I'd still like to get it fixed.

So does anyone here know how to change the icon without editing the file name of `os_ubuntu.icns` to `os_linux.icns`?

Answer (score 2):

Ordinarily, rEFInd will detect an Ubuntu installation and display the correct icon for it. If that's not working, though, check [this section of the rEFInd documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html#hiding) (the bulleted list specifies a number of ways to change the icon that rEFInd uses). If the icons in question boot a Linux kernel directly, then changing the filesystem name is likely to be the cleanest solution. For instance, if the kernel is on `/dev/sda5`, and if it uses ext2fs, ext3fs, or ext4fs, you might type:

```
sudo tune2fs -L ubuntu /dev/sda5
```

If you need more help, please say how rEFInd identifies the boot loader(s) that have the generic Tux icon -- that is, what text is displayed beneath the icons when you highlight an entry?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used refind (are you kidding me with that capitalization?) but can't you just edit the stanza?

http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html#stanzas

Quote:

> icon | filename | Sets the filename for an icon for the menu. If you
>   omit this item, a    default icon will be used, based on rEFInd's
>   auto-detection algorithms. The filename should    be a complete path
>   from the root of the current directory, not relative to the default 
>   icons subdirectory or the one set via icons_dir.

That seems to be the problem and the solution.

Comment: lovely capitalization isn't it?

Comment: This solution will work if rEFInd is being used via manual boot stanzas, but most users don't use it in this way. It's generally easier to use rEFInd with automatic kernel detection, and for that, another solution is required, as specified in my full response.